# Custom RecyclerView is null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to extend `RecyclerView` but the app crashes because the custom recycler view is null.

**MyRecyclerView.kt**

```
class MyRecyclerView @JvmOverloads constructor
    (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyle: Int = 0)
    : RecyclerView(context), RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    override fun onTouchEvent(p0: RecyclerView, p1: MotionEvent) {
        // no op
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(p0: Boolean) {
        // no op
    }
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<com.myapp.view.MyRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:itemCount="1"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_item"
    tools:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Here is where it crashes in `onViewCreated()` in the fragment:

```
binding.root.myRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
binding.root.myRecyclerView.layoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

with this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: binding.root.myRecyclerView must not
>   be null

Not sure what why this `RecyclerView` is null. Thanks.

Comment: You must pass the `AttributeSet` to the super constructor. Otherwise the ID is never set on the `View`. You're only passing the `Context`, for all four constructors, it seems.

Comment: This solved it @MikeM. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `View`'s ID defined with the `android:id` XML attribute is in the `AttributeSet` passed into the two+ parameter constructors. If you don't pass that in the super constructor call, the ID will not be set automatically in the `View` class, and your custom `View` won't be found with `findViewById()`.

In this case, we just need to add the rest of the parameters to the super call:

```
RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyle)
```

You might also want to set the appropriate `defStyle` default, which is `R.attr.recyclerViewStyle`, in the newest library versions, at least.